# How to run Lubuntu 14.04 in non GUI

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, gui

I want to be able to run Lubuntu 14.04 in non GUI mode.  I also want an easy way to switch between the two modes.

Comment: CTRL+ALT+F1 to go to non GUI mode and CTRL+ALT+F7 to switch!

Answer (score 2):

To switch to non-GUI/Terminal mode press

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

<kbd>F2</kbd>,<kbd>F3</kbd>and<kbd>F4</kbd> also works

TO switch back to GUI mode press

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>

Or sometimes
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>

Comment: When I do CTRL ALT F1 it opens TTY1, but I cannot open programs from there.  It says no X11 display open.

Comment: are you trying to open a gui program on a non-gui environment?

Comment: I tried opening firefox, but it did not open.  If I wanted to open a web browser, what could I use?  The Lubuntu file manager, pcmanfm, does not open either.

Comment: go back to gui mode and open firefox

Comment: Firefox is open.  Also, I can open firefox through LXTerminal fine.  Midori, the browser I normaly use, opens the same way as firefox.

Comment: Please explain.